# Is docker only used for applications that based on micro-service architecture

Tags: docker, microservices, virtualization, linux-containers

I am totally new to this... So please explain in layman's terms.

We want to shift our application(actually my employer application, currently using Weblogic server) to micro-service architecture and deploy each component to individual containers(planning to use docker).

My concern is, can we only use docker for applications that are based on micro-service architecture or we can use docker for any kind of application. I am sure, I am missing something here and there.

Please Explain the whole process in simple terms as I am a newbie in this technology.

Answer (score 0):

it is not mandatory to use Docker in microservices architecture. you can design your system/Application and use microservices architecture and the final deployment can be pure hardware.

At the end, a microservice can be treated as a process that needs a host to run. this host can be docker host or any operating system that can run this process.

for legacy application as yours, you can use Docker too. instead of your normal infrastructure, you can containerize your application and ship to Docker